# DAG, search for cheapest descendants with same color

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a DAG. For each $v\in V$ you have a color $c(v): V \rightarrow \left\{c_1 \ldots c_k \right\}$ where $k$ is a fixed number, and a weight $p(v)$. For every $v \in V$ you have to find its descendant that has the same color and the lowest weight.

The problem requires an algorithm that runs in linear time.

A naive approach would use a search in topological order but that has $O(n^2)$ running time because you should perform it for every node.

Another idea could be reverse edges and do a visit starting from the sink. Then you may mantain a map that keeps updated the lowest encountered $p(v)$ corresponding to each color $c_k$, and assign the correct value to every discovered $v$. But what if there are more sinks?

Any suggestion to do this in linear time?

**Edited**

I'm wondering if the following may work (to simplify it keeps the lowest p(v) and not the node itself):

```
merge(src, dest)
  for i = 1 to k
    if src[c_i] < dest[c_i] then dest[c_i] = src[c_i]

visit(v,E,G)
  visited[v]=true
  map = [] array of k infinities
  for (v,u) in E do
    if visited(u) = false then
      map_u = visit(u, E, G)
      merge(map_u, map)
    else 
      map_u = maps(u)
      merge(map_u, map)
    end if
  end for
  maps[v] = copy of map
  cost[v] = map[c(v)]
  if p(v) < map[c(v)] then map[c(v)] = p[v]
  return map

search(V,E)
  visited = new array of |V| elements
  for each v in V do: visited(v) = false
  for each v in V do:
    if visited[v] = false then visit(v, V, E)
  end for
```

Comment: If $n$ is the number of vertices, then it's somewhat doubtful that linear time suffices, since you might have to go over all edges, and there could be many of them.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus text is vague about this, it says that has to be linear respect to the size of the graph, so $O(|V|+|E|)$. I think one could keep a map in any node $v$ to summarize, at that point, min. discovered descendant weights for each color. For example, using DFS. If the search encounters already visited node, just use its associated map and return to source. However if think i'm missing something.

Comment: @RickyDemer yes, i'm interested in a solution assuming k is costant (used the term "fixed" probably incorrect). Can this simplify and bring to a linear time solution? In which way?

Comment: ... Oh ... I read your question too quickly and somehow missed that. ​ (Your use of "fixed" is fine.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Either DFS or a topological sorting framework works. Actually, [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Tarjan.27s_algorithm) for topological sorting is based on DFS. You can follow the [DFS framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode) to solve your problem.

Comment: @hengxin thanks for you hint. Effectively, my attempt is based on dfs. It should use topological order implicitly, but in reverse direction: you can know cheapest descendants only after a walk is complete and you are coming back from sinks. So any decision is made in the postvisit step. Is it the same idea as yours? I'm wondering if "state saving" into nodes through $maps$ array is correct or there is a better way. I think that having $k$ constant helps to obtain linear time because it allows to use arrays. With arbitrary $k$ one should use a dictionary or such, with bigger running times.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on (1) making decisions at `post-visit` steps and (2) using an array of size $k$ for each vertex to save states. It is linear.